# How to do Autocomplete text suggestion in message box in BOT

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I created a BOT with LUIS and node.js and also published in Skype Channel.

Now I wants to add Autocomplete text suggestion in message box.

Am unable to find documentation for node.js

Please assist me.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? jQuery autocomplete is quite easy to implement: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Autcomplete can be accomplished with a few different NPM packages. Here's one as an example that looks not too bad to implement: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autocompleter

Code example:

```
var countries = [
    { label: 'United Kingdom', value: 'UK' },
    { label: 'United States', value: 'US' }
];

autocomplete({
    input: document.getElementById("country"),
    fetch: function(text, update) {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        // you can also use AJAX requests instead of preloaded data
        var suggestions = countries.filter(n => n.label.toLowerCase().startsWith(text))
        update(suggestions);
    },
    onSelect: function(item) {
        alert(item.value); // will display 'US' or 'UK'
    }
});
```

You'll obviously have to adapt this to your needs and exact use case, but should be easy enough to implement.